# How can you get an extension removed from the VSCode marketplace?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I forked a VSCode extension that the developer had stopped maintaining, and created a new version of it with extra functionality that I added to the marketplace, and that I will maintain. I already spoke with the original maintainer, and they are happy for my new extension to take the place of the old one.

However, they can no longer access their account to remove the old extension, does anyone know of any way to resolve this so people only find the new improved extension?

Comment: That developer should contact the marketplace support, and convince them to give him access to his account.